# Y-Axis Range Control for Dygraph Time Series

Tags: javascript, visualization, dygraphs

I'm working on generating time series figures with Dygraphs and I would like to add improved vertical control for my figures. Specifically, I want to be able to zoom out incrementally rather than being forced to zoom out entirely or not at all.

I'm flexible about the solution. Making a vertical range selector would be great, but if there are simpler solutions like including text boxes that control the vertical range that would be great as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the y-axis range however you like using `updateOptions`:

```
g.updateOptions({valueRange: [min, max]});
```

See the [link-interaction](http://dygraphs.com/tests/link-interaction.html) demo for a fully-worked example. It uses links to set the x-axis range (`dateWindow`), but it's the same idea.